# 昼飯食ったら また行こうぜ - What grammar is the kuttara in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering what 昼飯食ったら grammar is used in this sentence?

I am wondering if it is the past conditional as described by Tae Kim here:

http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/conditionals

But it doesn't quite fit into what Google translate gives me.

I get this from Google Translate:

"After having lunch".

So is this really the 'past conditional' as described by Tae Kim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ったら Does mean if, but has a connotation of when. In this case, the sentence means, "lets go when/after/once we finish lunch". So yes, Tae Kim's description of what he calls 'past conditionals' would be correct.

> 家に帰ったら、誰もいなかった。
>
> When I went home, there was no one there.

Is a prime example.

There a a lot of other pages on this site which describe usages of ったら. Many of them have really good examples sentences, I would take a look at those. Here are a few

[How certain is たら？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40056/how-certain-is-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89)

[Other uses of the たら conditional](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30516/other-uses-of-the-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-conditional)

[Meaning of 〜たら in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19669/meaning-of-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-in-this-sentence)

Comment: 「昼飯食ったらまた行こうぜ。」の「食ったら」は（近い）未来の出来事を指していて、「家に帰ったら、誰もいなかった。」の「家に帰ったら」は終了済みの過去の出来事を指しているので、質問者への回答中の例文としての使用にはかなり無理があるのでは？